# Couldnot update time stamp Error when running 'react-native run-android' in gc.properties ( react-native )

Tags: android, reactjs, gradle, react-native

When I am running `react-native run-android` it says :

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

`* What went wrong:
Could not update time stamp for /home/userName/Desktop/hello-world/android/.gradle/4.10.2/gc.properties`

Upon running `--stacktrace`, it shows :

`* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Could not update time stamp for /home/userName/Desktop/hello-world/android/.gradle/4.10.2/gc.properties`.

What can be the possible reason of this? I searched it a lot but failed to find a solution.

Comment: Not sure, but are the SDK build tools, images, ... are the versions required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved. I deleted `gc.properties` and then gave all permissions to my react-native project. Main problem was related to permissions.